# Validate message cakephp error?

Tags: validation, message

how can I custom a message validate in cakephp like that ???

```
$value=$this->data['value'];
'count_device' => array(
                    'rule' => 'checkvalues',
                    'message' =>'Value must be greater than or equal to'.$value;
                   ));
```

the message is error how to fix ????

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this,

```
$value=$this->data['value'];
'count_device' => array(
                    'rule' => 'checkvalues',
                    'message' =>'Value must be greater than or equal to'.$value;
                   ));

public function checkvalues($value,$context){
        if($context['data']['count_device'] > $value) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I mean , i want to display the message  ex :"Value must be greater than or equal to 8" with 8 is $value. i try 'Value must be greater than or equal to'.$value; this wrong :'(

Comment: if(!empty($error_msg)){
                    $this->Flash->error(
                        __("Please fix the following error(s):".implode("\n \r", $error_msg))
                    );
                }

Comment: you can check the message in controller